# If cell on Sheet 1 meets a criteria, paste cells 1, 2 and 3 from this row into Sheet 2 next empty row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's my issue: I have a spreadsheet where I write down all my clients' visits information, like name, contact, phone, etc, and also (in column R:R) if my team needs to call them or not.

I want to copy all the client information and paste it in the next empty row of sheet 2 if the criteria is met on column R:R.

I did it with a simple If else formula, but the problem is that I couldn't paste the content into the "next empty row" but only in the same row that I got the data, for example:

~ Sheet 2 B2 ~

```
=IF(Visits!R2="Yes";Visits!B2)
```

~ Sheet B C2 ~

```
=IF(Visits!R2="Yes";Visits!C2)
```

...

But like I said, using this formula I can not copy the data to the next empty row, but only to the same row that the original data is.

I know nothing about VBA and not much about Excel formulas, can someone help me, please?

Comment: Cant you use a filter?

Comment: Yes i can, but i really wanted to copy this data to a separate sheet

Comment: You could reference all cells from Sheet1 in Sheet2 and apply a filter in Sheet2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Sheet2!B2, and then fill right and down.

```
=INDEX(visits!B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(visits!$R$2:INDEX(visits!$R:$R, MATCH("zzz", visits!$R:$R)))/(visits!$R$2:INDEX(visits!$R:$R, MATCH("zzz", visits!$R:$R))="yes"), ROW(1:1)))&""
```

Comment: Does it work on google sheets also? I got an error, but there's a high chance that i did something wrong...

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeida if you want google sheets formula then you need to tag it google sheets and not Excel.  Though many formula are the same, many are not.

Comment: Okay, i'm sorry